# Settings Bundle toggle switch only returns YES

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, settings-bundle

I have added a settings bundle to my application consisting of a number of toggle switches, It is being used to display different images depending on which toggle is active.  This works fine the first time but once the values has been set to YES it always returns YES.

I have deleted the data within NSUserDefaults using the below

```
NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

which works if the settings are changed before every launch of the application.  (not ideal).  Has anyone come across this and know how the values can be updated and persist? Below is my code where i am retrieving and seeing from BOOL value

```
BOOL setImageOne = (BOOL)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"ladbrokes"];
BOOL setImageTwo = (BOOL)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"williamHill"];

if (setImageOne) {
    self.clientLogoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clientOneLogo.png"];
}

if (setImageTwo) {
    self.clientLogoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clientTwoLogo.png"];
}

NSString *appDomain = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:appDomain];
```

Comment: Add the code where you set and more importantly read the value.

Comment: Please read [Getting and Setting Preference Values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-97383), check the return type of `valueForKey:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bool will be stored within an `NSNumber` object, as primitive types cannot be stored in Objective-C collection classes, so this statement:

```
BOOL setImageOne = (BOOL)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"ladbrokes"];
```

is basically the same as:

```
NSNumber *boolObj = @(NO);
BOOL b = (BOOL)boolObj;      // b == YES
```

when what you intended was:

```
BOOL b = [boolObj boolValue];   // b == NO
```

Use `[NSUserDefaults boolForKey]` instead.